# MySQL add 12 hours to a time field

Tags: mysql

I need to add 12 hours to a MySQL `TIME` field (not `DATETIME`) and I'm having trouble.

```
UPDATE `events` 
SET start_time = DATE_ADD(start_time, INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
WHERE `start_time` < '11:00:00'
```

returns with no errors but doesn't change anything, I think because `start_time` is a `TIME` field.

```
UPDATE `events` 
SET start_time = start_time + '12:00:00'
WHERE `start_time` < '11:00:00'
```

adds 12 seconds.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try using ADDTIME instead of DATE_ADD.  You could do `SET start_time = ADDTIME(start_time, '12:00:00')`

Comment: @sdfor: Glad to hear it. For manuals, I tend to rely more on the online content.  For mysql, you can use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/

Answer (score 12):

```
UPDATE `events` 
SET start_time = start_time + INTERVAL 12 HOUR
WHERE `start_time` < '11:00:00'
```

The MySQL functions that accept `INTERVAL` arguments are mostly unnecessary; you can just add and subtract intervals with `+` and `-`.

Comment: This query should work, and does still work as of MySQL 5.7.11. Possible typo or bug in your point release, perhaps?

Comment: You're right Aaron,   SELECT now() + INTERVAL 12 HOUR;  is working.  Maybe last time something was wrong with my DB connection or something.  I tested just now on 5.6 and 5.5.   I've deleted my first comment to not confuse future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

```
set start_time = ADDTIME(start_time,'12:00:00')
```

DATE_ADD works fine with timestamp etc, but not with TIME

Answer (score 3):

```
update my_table SET modified_date = ADDTIME(scheduled_date, '03:15:00')
```

This will add 3 hours , 15 minutes in modified_date

Answer (score 1):

if the developer does not want to update data and wants to add hours or minutes to time. It can be done following way:

The developer can use an AddTime() function to [add hours to time column in MySQL](http://guruquest.net/question/how-to-add-hour-or-minutes-to-time-column-in-mysql/).
It can be used like below way:

```
AddTime(COLUMN,’01:00:00′) to add an hour in MySQL time column
AddTime(COLUMN,’00:01:00′) to add a minute in MySQL time column
```

sql query example:

```
select id,name,AddTime(login_time,'01:00:00') as login_time FROM `table`
```

Answer (score 0):

First answer:
`SET start_time = ADDTIME(start_time, '12:00:00')`

Will only work if start_time is less than 12 hours.

If start_time is for example 13:00:00, then the end result will be 25:00:00, to get 01:00:00, you can use the following trick:

```
SET start_time = DATE_FORMAT(ADDTIME(CONCAT('1970-01-01 ', start_time), '12:00:00'), '%H:%i:%s')
```

(I used this to correct for the timezone)