# Mysql DATE_ADD not working with INTERVAL reserved word

Tags: mysql

I need to run the following query:

```
select DATE_ADD('08:35:00', INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) from dual
```

But I get **null** instead of **08:40:00** as expected. What am I doing wrong?

I need to use the INTERVAL x MINUTE format because the number 5 will be replaced by an integer variable later.

Comment: works: select DATE_ADD('2016-11-11 08:35:00', INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)

Comment: Not only `time`, but also `date`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql add 12 hours to a time field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840833/mysql-add-12-hours-to-a-time-field)

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/a/38558899/1203805 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using [ADDTIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) instead of `DATE_ADD`?

```
select ADDTIME('08:35:00.000000', '00:05:00.000000') from dual
```

Comment: Is there a way I can still use the INTERVAL reserved word?

Answer (score 0):

[DATEADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) expects first argument to be date or datetime, got time.

Use [ADDTIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) instead:

```
SELECT ADDTIME('08:35:00', '0:05:00');
```

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/70627)

You may use this query with variables as you mentioned above using [LPAD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad):

```
SET @a = 5;
SELECT ADDTIME('08:35:00', CONCAT('0:', LPAD(@a, 2, '0'), ':00'));
```

[Demo 2.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/70633)

Answer (score 0):

I tried executing your query ending up with the same result, try add a specific day before the time. it works fine with mine. eg:

**You can change the date**

```
select DATE_ADD('2016-11-05 08:35:00', INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) as    future_time from dual
```

or

```
select ADDTIME('08:35:00','00:05:00')as future_time from dual
```

Comment: I do want to get '08:40:00' as answer and not '2016-11-05 08:40:40'. What should I do then?

Comment: You can use ADDTIME function to sum up time together eg:  select ADDTIME('08:35:00','00:05:00')as future_time from dual   @DanielCalderonMori

Answer (score 0):

Cause you need to use `INTERVAL`, and if you did not care about date, you can do it like this:

```
select time(DATE_ADD('2016-01-01 08:35:00', INTERVAL 5 MINUTE));
```

Or maybe the `date_format` is what you want:

```
select date_format(DATE_ADD('2016-01-01 08:35:00', INTERVAL 5 MINUTE), '%H:%i:%s');
```

[<kbd>Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/70630)

Comment: That seems to get the job done. Although I'm a little worried to introduce a wildly arbitrary value that could damage readability.

Comment: @DanielCalderonMori Then I think you have to use `addtime`. :-(