# Trying to add 8 hours to multiple date timestamps in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a MySQL query that retrieves a date/timestamp field in this format: '2016-08-01 12:00:00'. My problem is I need to add 8 hours to the time stamp AND adjust the date field too. Is this even possbile?

Examples:

'2016-08-01 00:00:02' would return '2016-08-01 08:00:02' 
AND
'2016-07-31 23:00:02' would return '2016-08-01 07:00:02'

My date/time field is named 'zoning_log.date'

I've tried this: 
Select
ADDTIME( 'zoning_log.date','0 8:00:00.00') 
which returns '08:00:00'

Thank you for your help

Comment: See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840833/mysql-add-12-hours-to-a-time-field

Answer (score 1):

It's extremely simple:

```
SELECT zoning_log.date + INTERVAL 8 hour
```

If you'd need to add some arbitrary day/hour/minute/second value, then it's a bit more difficult. But for a simple "adjust by X hours" or whatever, it's literally this trivial.

Comment: Thanks Marc! That was the solution I needed for for the time. So easy. I tried a million things. Next challenge is the get the date field handled. Thanks again.

Comment: @paula. What do you mean by the date field? Surely date and time are stored as a single entity, right?